# Setting native library path

Tags: java, java-native-interface, path

My native library resides at `C:\Mywork`.

How do I set the native library path towards `C:\Mywork` using both command prompt line and the path variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the PATH variable as follows:

```
C:\> set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Mywork
```

And on the java command-line like so:

```
C:\> java -Djava.library.path=C:\Mywork MyMainClass
```